# What APIs can be used to understand how crowded a certain place right now?

Tags: ios, api, google-places-api

Aim is to understand how many people is in some restaurant, cafe, bar, night club or other public place via data from open sources.
I know about different social APIs, but want to find any ways how to rank places by crowdedness without being logged in any social. Suppose I search places at google map at ios device, then click at some bar, get data and of course latitude and longitude of this place from google place api. Can I find information about quantity of people that are located at bar right now? What other open sources you can suggest? Perhaps it can be achieved via Instagram or twitter. Any tips, suggestions or algorithms?